# Need iPhone Human Interface Tutorial!

Tags: iphone, macos, ios

I have just spent little time with iOS. Anybody can tell me how to construct a nice Human Interface in iPhone. Give me advices, tutorials or something help me to learn how to construct a nice iPhone Human Interface. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked [at this document](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html)? It surely is the starting point for everyone programming for iPhone/iPod touch/iPad

Answer (score 1):

Have you read Apple's Human Interface Guidelines document?  It's available from http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: +1, The HIG is really what you are looking for. It contains lots of examples of good and bad UIs